# How to query ES infomation using Celebro in JavaCode

Tags: elasticsearch

How to login Cerebro with username and password in JavaCode?
And query ES information with Cerebro rest api?

Comment: Please add more details on how does the code you tried look so far and what is the error you are getting.

Comment: I don't know how to login cerebro in JavaCode, for example sending a http request with username and password in it?

Comment: Please provide some code you have tried so far and error you are getting. Please include this in the question itself. Also please make sure to specify the technologies you are asking about precisely. With "JavaCode", do you mean Java Script or Java? What is "Celebro"? Maybe add a link at at least for me quick online search did not found anything relevant.

Comment: sorry, it's cerebro. and it's github link is https://github.com/lmenezes/cerebro.   JavaCode used to send http request I guess is like HttpUtils.get(ip, params) , but I don't know exactly what to send to cerebro to get it's overview page data.

Comment: I see, cool. Please add these fixes and additional data directly to your question.